# Generate a table in word using excel data

Tags: excel, ms-word

[Data in this list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZ2rh.png) is required to be formatted in a table in MS Word so I can make a simple catalog with similar to [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/07Ud7.png) I have a long list of items so I need a faster and easier way to prepare the catalog, I intend to save it as a PDF afterwards, by placing company logo in page header. Any easier way to do this without having to pay for a catalog service is much appreciated

Comment: Mail merge would best way to do it without any vba coding. You can also it in excel but need vba to do that. Search on google for mail merge.

Comment: I'm working on figuring out how to use mail merge, since i have never used it before.. will post again if i can't manage, thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply take the whole table from excel to word by selecting the whole table in excel then copying it and pasting it in the word file.
Another way is to create a table in the word file having exact number of rows and columns in your excel table. And than pasting the excel table data to the word table.

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).